# Not getting a response from a power meter if the string is too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am using this code to communicate with a power meter:

```
def Hello() :
    answer = SendMessage("\x10\x49\x01\x00\x4A\x16","100b01000c16")
    if answer == 1:
        answer = SendMessage("\x10\x40\x01\x00\x41\x16","100001000116")
    if answer == 1:
        answer = SendMessage("\x10\x49\x01\x00\x4A\x16","100b01000c16")
    if answer == 1:
        answer = SendMessage("\x68\x0D\x0D\x68\x73\x01\x00\xB7\x01\x06\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x34\x16","100001000116")   
    if answer ==  1:
        input3 = input ("progress")

def SendMessage(message, expected):
    out = ''
    while out == '':
        # send the character to the device
        print (message)
        ser.write(message.encode())
        #Let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(0.02)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.readline().hex()
            if out != '':
                print (">>>>" + out)
                if out == expected:
                    print("Correct response")
                    out = ''
                    answer = 1
                    return answer
                else:
                    print("Incorrect response")
                    answer = 0
                    return answer

OpenComm = Hello()
```

The code is far from ideal. It's just a proof of concept right now.

According to a log I have from this same power meter, when I send

```
68 0D 0D 68 73 01 00 B7 01 06 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 34 16
```

it should reply with

```
10 00 01 00 01 16
```

but right now it's not doing anything when I send that specific message (it does respond to the previous ones though). Could it be that the hex is too long? If so, any ideas on how I can fix that?

This is how I configured the serial port:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port = "COM3",
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also, if your code is nested more than ~4 times your probably should question if you are doing something wrong. (Your code is nested 11 times!). Consider using functions to shorten and clean up your code. It will make finding the bug a massive amount easier to find.

Comment: It's nested but it only did the same thing over and over. I created a function that does that to make it more readable.

Comment: Correct but the issue is "only did the same thing over and over". General rule of thumb, if you EVER copy and paste a block of code more then once in coding, you are not doing proper software development. The same error occurs with this new code correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting exactly the same result.

Comment: You could have many different problems but oftentimes when you can't connect to a serial device you have a hardware issue or you are not interpreting correctly the protocol. Can you name the brand and model of the power meter? If you do we can double check your settings and commands.

Comment: I AM connecting to the power meter though. I'm getting the correct response for the first 3 messages. The last one is the only one with issues. The power meter is a Circutor Cirwatt 405-VT7A-96B-10.

Comment: No wonder your commands seemed familiar... see my answer below. There are some attempts to the IEC 870-5-102 protocol out there, see for instance [here](https://github.com/javierdelapuente/reeprotocol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tiny but important problem in your code.

The notation you are using for raw bytes as a string `"\x10\x49\x01\x00\x4A\x16"` should actually be `b"\x10\x49\x01\x00\x4A\x16"`.

This is no problem when you send short commands because those don't have any non-ASCII characters. But on your long command, you have `\xB7`. If you try the following:

```
>>> b"\xb7"=="\xb7".encode()
```

on your Python interpreter, you'll get: `False`.

And if you do:

```
>>> "\x68\x0D\x0D\x68\x73\x01\x00\xB7\x01\x06\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x34\x16".encode()
```

you'll get:

```
b'h\r\rhs\x01\x00\xc2\xb7\x01\x06\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x004\x16'
```

So you see when you encode `"\xB7`:

```
>>> "\xb7".encode()
```

you get `b'\xc2\xb7'` meaning you are sending one spurious byte.

To fix it just correct the notation adding `b"...` to your commands and drop the `.encode()` when you write to the port.

Before realizing the problem I thought there might be something wrong in the syntaxis of your command. But checking against [this document](http://oa.upm.es/39933/3/TFG_Jara_Suarez_de_Puga_Garcia.pdf), everything seems to be in order (other than the device address and the checksum your command is exactly the same as the one on page 83). I cannot be 100% certain that fixing the notation will solve your problem but I'm very optimistic.

**EDIT**: As discussed in the comments below, there is also the fact that `serial.write()` works as non-blocking so it returns immediately. Since writing a certain number of bytes to the bus (at the speed indicated by the baud rate) will take some time. A back-of-the-envelope calculation for your case, if you wait for 20 ms (with `time.sleep(0.02)`), the buffer will write around 9600 bps*(20ms/1000ms)*0.1bytes/1bit=19 bytes.

This might be enough for your short commands, but considering you should allow for a short while to give time to the meter to react to the command and send back its answer, for a long command you might need to increase the delay to maybe 50-100 ms.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and the first messages still work but the longer doesn't. As you can see in the code I posted in the question, I'm printing "message" and in that long one this is what's I'm seeing:

b'h\r\rhs\x01\x00\xb7\x01\x06\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x004\x16'

Which is pretty similar to what you said I'd see if I didn't implement the modification you mentioned.

Comment: Did you remove the `.encode()` from the  `ser.write(message.encode())` line?. `message` will be correct as soon as you add the `b` to it, it's the `.encode()` what is screwing it up. If your short commands work and the long one is proper, you should get an answer back from the meter even if you are using the wrong password.

Comment: What I mean is: your short commands working prove you have a good connection and the right settings and the only scenario in which the meter is not answering at all to a long command is when such long command is not properly composed. I'm far from infallible but as far as I can tell your command is proper, so... what remains should be the right answer: there is still something wrong with the way you are sending your long commamd

Comment: Another thing you might want to try is to increase the `time.sleep(0.02)` to something like 100 ms. 20ms might be a bit too tight for the meter to give you an answer, heck it's barely enough for the meter to receive the command (20 ms at 9.6k gives you time to write less than 20 bytes to the bus)

Comment: That was it! I increased the sleep time and it worked right away. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: you're welcome. I've added the comment to my answer. Have fun with your power readings.